# Nokogiri pull parser (Nokogiri::XML::Reader) issue with self closing tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, xml-parsing

I have a huge XML(>400MB) containing products. Using a DOM parser is therefore excluded, so i tried to parse and process it using a pull parser. Below is a snippet from the `each_product(&block)` method where i iterate over the product list.

Basically, using a stack, i transform each `<product> ... </product>` node into a hash and process it.

```
while (reader.read)
  case reader.node_type
    #start element
    when Nokogiri::XML::Node::ELEMENT_NODE
      elem_name = reader.name.to_s
      stack.push([elem_name, {}])

    #text element
    when Nokogiri::XML::Node::TEXT_NODE, Nokogiri::XML::Node::CDATA_SECTION_NODE
      stack.last[1] = reader.value

    #end element
    when Nokogiri::XML::Node::ELEMENT_DECL
      return if stack.empty?

      elem = stack.pop
      parent = stack.last
      if parent.nil?
        yield(elem[1])
        elem = nil
        next
      end

      key = elem[0]
      parent_childs = parent[1]
    # ... 
      parent_childs[key] =  elem[1]
    end
```

The issue is on self-closing tags (EG `<country/>`), as i can not make the difference between a 'normal' and a 'self-closing' tag. They both are of type `Nokogiri::XML::Node::ELEMENT_NODE` and i am not able to find any other discriminator in the [documentation](http://nokogiri.rubyforge.org/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Reader.html).

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: I found this feature request: http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/issues/#issue/262

Comment: The only way is to check if the content is empty or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [feature request](http://github.com/tenderlove/nokogiri/issues/#issue/262) on project page regarding this issue (with the corresponding [failing test](http://gist.github.com/392060)).

Until it will be fixed and pushed into the current version, we'll stick with good'ol

```
input_text.gsub! /<([^<>]+)\/>/, '<\1></\1>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey Vlad, well I am  not a Nokogiri expert but I've done a test and saw that the self_closing?() method works fine on determining the self closing tags. Give it a try.

P.S. : I know this is an old post :P / the documentation is [HERE](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Reader.html#method-i-self_closing%3F)